# Why Project Reactor's Mono doesn't have a share() operator?

Tags: project-reactor

I'd like to "share" a Mono as I do with Flux.

Flux share() example with Kotlin:

```
fun `test flux share`() {
        val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(2)

        val originalFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(200))
                .map { "$it = ${Instant.now()}" }
                .take(7)
                .share()
                .doOnTerminate {
                    countDownLatch.countDown()
                }


        println("Starting #1...")

        originalFlux.subscribe {
            println("#1: $it")
        }

        println("Waiting ##2...")
        CountDownLatch(1).await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        println("Starting ##2...")

        originalFlux.subscribe {
            println("##2: $it")
        }

        countDownLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        println("End!")
    }
```

I couldn't find a share() operator to Mono. Why doesn't it exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I couldn't find a share() operator to Mono. Why doesn't it exist?

**The specific behaviour of `share()` doesn't make much sense with a Mono, but we have `cache()` which may be what you're after.**

`share()` is equivalent to you calling `publish().refcount()` on your Flux. Specifically, `publish()` gives you a `ConnectableFlux`, or a "hot" flux. (`refcount()` just automatically connects / stops the flux based on the first / last subscriber.)

The "raison d'être" for `ConnectableFlux` is allowing multiple subscribers to subscribe whenever they wish, missing the data that was emitted before they subscribed. In the case of `Mono` this doesn't make a great deal of sense, as by definition there is only one value emitted - so if you've missed it, then you've missed it.

However, we do have [cache()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache--) on Mono, which also turns it into a "hot" source (where the original supplier isn't called for each subscription, just once on first subscribe.) The obvious difference from above is that the value is replayed for every subscriber, but that's almost certainly what you want.

*(Sidenote if you test the above - note that you'll need to use `Mono.fromSupplier()` rather than `Mono.just()`, as the latter will just grab the value once at instantiation, thus `cache()` has no meaningful effect.)*

Answer (score 3):

From Project Reactor `3.4.x` onwards we have [`Mono#share()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.12-SNAPSHOT/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#share--)

> Prepare a Mono which shares this Mono result similar to Flux.shareNext(). This will effectively turn this Mono into a hot task when the first Subscriber subscribes using subscribe() API. Further Subscriber will share the same Subscription and therefore the same result. It's worth noting this is an un-cancellable Subscription.